# Autolayout align to center (vertically or horizontally) with constant

Tags: objective-c, xcode, alignment, autolayout

New to autolayout but confused about constant.

I have a UIView object in the middle both horizontally and vertically centered align. What does changing the constant actually do? It seems to move the UIView in ratio (which is what I want) but I'll like to understand this value more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The constant in this case is merely an offset.  If the first item in the constraint is your UIView and it is constrained to the centerX of its superview, then the constant just moves the view right (for a positive value) or left (for a negative value).  The movement is in points, not pixels.

There is also a multiplier associated with the constraint.  This multiplies the horizontal value of the centerX for instance.  If you make the multiplier `2` and the constant is `0`, you'll end up centered at the right edge of the superview.  If you make the multiplier `0.00001` (*Interface Builder* won't let you set it to `0`), you'll end up centered at the left edge of the superview.